# How to configure notification on degraded RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

I am planning a RAID1(mirror) array in a NAS using either a Hardware or Software RAID controller using Linux.

Though I did not find any documentation in which way the system will notify me that the RAID is degraded.

I dont want to actively check for degration. I suppose there is some way to configure a "mail to root" when degration is noticed ?

How does a HW raid communicate a degraded disk to the system at all ? Do I need to install raidcard-specific software to know ?

Comment: That depends on the raid controller.

Comment: and please decide if it's a software raid or hw raid, don't tag both, and please update the question to be precise as possible

Comment: Well it is nothing currently. I want to decide which one to go for, HW or SW, based on the possibility to notify on degration. Should I better ask two separate questions than ?

Comment: this platform will not help you to utilize what platform would be the best due to the opinion bases answers. however, in most cases, hw raid will be the option and the better solution and choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases the raid itself will not notify you. You will have to use software or a script to poll the status of the raid periodically and notify you via email or other ways.

For the mdraid based software raids you can use mdadm for monitoring and for others there are different ways.

You can get inspiration from check_raid which is commonly used with nagios/naemon monitoring, but you can use it as a standalone script.

[check_raid](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/RAID-Controllers/check_raid/details)